# Golang Wasm HTTP Request Failing

Tags: http, go, webassembly

I'm a little stuck on a Golang wasm request.  The code works just fine in a service when I test it, but when I try to run it in a browser with wasm I get a fetch failed error.  This code runs just fine if I call it from a stand-alone service:

```golang
go func() {
        authURL := "https://auth.home.rsmachiner.com/login"
        type loginStruct struct {
            Username string `json:"username"`
            Password string `json:"password"`
        }
        fmt.Println("Pushed login button")
        fmt.Printf("Got Login: %v\n", r.LoginBoxValue)
        fmt.Printf("Got Password: %v\n", r.PasswordValue)
        var login loginStruct
        login.Username = r.LoginBoxValue
        login.Password = r.PasswordValue
        data, err := json.Marshal(&login)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(data))
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", authURL, bytes.NewBuffer(data))
        client := &http.Client{}
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("response error")
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Print("BODY:")
        fmt.Println(string(body))
    }()
```

Which throws the following error:

```
Post "https://auth.home.rsmachiner.com/login": net/http: fetch() failed: Failed to fetch
```

When I try it from a standalone client it works fine.  The server is allowing CORS as well with

```golang
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles on this, it works fine in a browser too.  The problem was the HTML not the code.  The HTML was making the page reload so the request was failing due to being terminated.